# Where do i get the View-IDs from Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

So i'm developing an Eclipse plugin, and i need to catch some errors

`ErrorViewPart ewp = new ErrorViewPart();
 IViewPart view = WorkbenchUtil.showViewInActiveWindow(ewp.getTitle());
 ErrorLog.toErrorLog(IStatus.ERROR, "No surefire-Path detected");`

The `ewp.getTitle()` seems to be wrong.
The Method `ErrorLog.toErrorLog` it's just a call from an own class to write to the ErrorLog.

Comment: What is `WorkbenchUtil`?  If `ErrorViewPart` is a view you don't construct it like this.

Comment: Its from org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.workbench.WorkbenchUtil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show a view you do **not** construct the view yourself. You ask Eclipse to construct and show the view:

```
IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
IViewPart viewPart = page.showView(viewId);
```

Here `viewId` is a view id which is a string declared in the `org.eclipse.ui.views` extension point. You find the ids for existing views by finding the declaring extension point or by using [Eclipse plugin spy](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#pluginspy)

Your code mentions `ErrorViewPart` - If this is `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ErrorViewPart` it is a special part which is not a normal view and is only opened when a error occurs opening a view or editor. Since it is in an **internal** package you should not be trying to access it directly.

Comment: Ty, this was very helpfull.

org.eclipse.pde.runtime.LogView ist the correct ID